# Get Image from Azure Blob using Proxy In Java

Tags: java, azure, blob

I need get Image from Azure blob storage container using Proxy and save the Image to BufferedImage.

```
             System.out.println("********Initiated******");

            //Set Proxy Host name and Port
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("xx-xx-xxxxx", 8080));
            OperationContext op = new OperationContext();
            op.setProxy(proxy);

            // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

            // Create the blob client.
           CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

           // Get a reference to a container.
           // The container name must be lower case
           CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("images");

            //call via this overload
            Iterable<ListBlobItem> blobs = container.listBlobs(null, false, EnumSet.noneOf(BlobListingDetails.class), new BlobRequestOptions(), op);

            URL urlOfImage = null; 
            //Listing contents of container
            for(ListBlobItem blob: blobs) { 
                /*Process the Image. Sample URL from Azure: **https://someWebsite.blob.core.windows.net/images/00001.png***/
                if(((CloudBlockBlob) blob).getName().toLowerCase().contains(".png")) {
                    urlOfImage = blob.getUri().toURL();
                    BufferedImage buffimage = ImageIO.read(urlOfImage);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("********Success*********");
```

By using the URI, i can open the image via browser(seperatly).

Question: I want to process the blob content directly or via URI. If i run my above code when i save Image to buffered Image,
 I get the following Error.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my experience, your issue was caused by the url of blob without SAS token which can not be accessed directly.

Here is my sample code to generate a blob url with SAS token.

```
String connectionString = "<your storage connection string>"
String containerName = "<your container name>";
String blobName = "<your blob name>";
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connectionString);
CloudBlobClient client = account.createCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = client.getContainerReference(containerName);
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(blobName);
SharedAccessBlobPolicy policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
policy.setPermissions(EnumSet.allOf(SharedAccessBlobPermissions.class));
policy.setSharedAccessStartTime(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().minusYears(2)));
policy.setSharedAccessExpiryTime(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().plusYears(2)));
String sas = blob.generateSharedAccessSignature(policy, null);
String urlWithSas = String.format("%s?%s", blob.getUri(), sas);
```

Then, you can pass the `urlWithSas` value to the method `ImageIO.read` without proxy to get its `BufferedImage` object, as below.

```
URL urlOfImage = new URL(urlWithSas);
BufferedImage buffimage = ImageIO.read(urlOfImage );
System.out.println(buffimage.getHeight());
```

It works for me.

For using proxy, you just need to follow the JDK offical document [`Java Networking and Proxies`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) to use `System.setProperty` method to enable networking with proxy for JVM at first.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "<your proxy host>");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "<your proxy port>");
```

---

Update:

The result of the code below is the same as the above.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlOfImage.openConnection();
conn.connect();
InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
BufferedImage buffimage = ImageIO.read(input);
```

Comment: I can get the URI. Is that good practice to get the Image by openconnection with proxy like "URLConnection conn = urlOfImage.openConnection(proxy);"

Comment: @PraveenGopal The same as good practice. It's up to you. I post the related code using `openConnection` which you can refer to.

Comment: Using Proxy: Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(HostName, 8080));
 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlOfImage.openConnection(proxy);

Comment: As info: If container access is not public level, use SharedAccessBlobPolicy