# Azure blob storage sdk v10/v11 quickstart error behind a proxy

Tags: java, proxy, azure-blob-storage

I've dowloaded and run the provided quickstat from github. It working well on a normal network but gives NPE if behind a proxy.

```
WARNING: An exception was thrown by com.microsoft.rest.v2.http.NettyClient$AcquisitionListener.operationComplete()
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.microsoft.rest.v2.http.NettyClient$AcquisitionListener.emitError(NettyClient.java:426)
```

When I updated to v11 (11.0.1) a new error appears instead of NPE, but not working at all.

```
WARN  NettyClient - Error emitted before channel is created. Message: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server
```

I've googled a lot and tried to set the default proxy in the operational context but no success.

```
OperationContext.setDefaultProxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyIP, proxyPort)));
```

Could you give me an updated (corrected) quickstart which works behind a proxy? Or give me some clue how, what to set and where?

Answer (score 0):

As I known, according to the Oracle document [`Java Networking and Proxies`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html), the simple way to access outside the proxy is to set `http[s].proxyHost` and `http[s].proxyPort` via `System.setProperty` in Java to make all programs on the JVM work behind a proxy. It works in my answer using older Azure Storage SDK for the other SO thread [Get Image from Azure Blob using Proxy In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55863696/get-image-from-azure-blob-using-proxy-in-java/55865101#55865101).

Comment: Thank you. I saw your post and tried to set the system proxy as well but the result is the same. Yor code gives the same NPE. I do a checking using wireshark and it seems the quicstart does not use the proxy at all (trying to resolve the dns only with onprem dns not via the proxy.